# How to avoid nesting sql query with row_number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

How would I avoid nesting this query. I think it bloats the query and makes it harrder to read. I am aware I can put `Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC)` inside the `where` clause but is there a way around that?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT [id], 
               [title], 
               [image], 
               [description], 
               [column5154], 
               [column5155], 
               [column5156], 
               RowNumber1 = Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) 
        FROM   [TestTable] x 
WHERE  x.rownumber1 % 5 = 0
```

Comment: Find a style you like better.  This is the right way to write the query (except for the syntax error).

Comment: You could place the inner query into a CTE.

Comment: You can try by creating a temporal table for storing the result of nested query. After that, you can select from this temporal table.

Comment: Note that you can't put the `Row_number() over (... )` inside the where clause. What you have is correct, except for the missing `)`

Comment: For standard queries, perhaps a table function, then it becomes a 1 liner Select * from dbo.MyFunct() where rownumber1 % 5 = 0

Comment: @Luis I think you mean temporary - temporal is something different.

Comment: You are right @AaronBertrand, temporary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want every fifth row, don't care about `RowNumber1`, and don't want to use a subquery, you can do:

```
select top (20) percent t.*
from testtable t
order by row_number() over (order by id asc)) % 5;
```

Window functions are allowed in the `order by`.  Personally, I think the subquery is easier to understand.

Comment: Agreed. Personally, I would go for CTE or subquery. It is cleaner and easier to understand. And there isn't any different in performance